# Coroutines with multithreading

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

So I've been trying to make this discord bot that uses yolov8 object detection model for inference. I'm running the inference function inside the `on_message` event, but due to it's blocking nature, I can't make more than one request at a time. I was able to make multiple threads for the model instance, and was able to deal with multiple requests in parallel. Now the issue I'm facing is with `message.channel.send` as it is a coroutine, but threads are only able to run synchronous functions. I was able to solve the messaging as well by using `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()` but only when I exclude `discord.ui.View()`.

code:

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} Here are your results: ",file= discord.File(fp=image_bytesio, filename="image.jpeg"), embeds=sendEmbed, view = discord.ui.View().add_item(discord.ui.Button(label="Join My Discord Server", emoji=emoji,style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, url="https://discord.gg/sERCEe"))), client.loop)
```

error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-92 (detect):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-36-5d42097b2506>", line 245, in detect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 192, in __init__
    self.__stopped: asyncio.Future[bool] = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

It works fine, when I don't add it. I checked the source code, and I think it's not being able to detect the loop. Is there a way, I can pass the running loop to it?

I have tried rummaging through, but couldn't anything useful

Comment: So to clarify, this error *only* occurs when you pass a view object into the function? Have you tried putting the coro into a var and then passing it?

Comment: you should use `asyncio.run_in_executor` from your async functions.  Not try to start async functions from threads not that are not asynchronous (which is what `call_soon_threadsafe`  attempts)

Comment: @jsbueno Hey so I ended up using `asyncio.to_thread()`, which is basically a wrapper around `run_in_executor`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BlueRobin Yes I did try that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Theonewordassaulter You could answer your own question if that worked

Answer (score 1):

Update: So what worked for me was, using `asyncio.to_thread`, which is what @jsbueno suggested. I simply run multiple threads, and return data to my async messaging function that's inside the `on_message` function/listener.